# Forward the request to other backend system on Apache webserver?

Tags: apache2

I want to forward my domain request to my backend systems without creating subdomain.
For example: `xyz.com` my domain, when anyone enter `1.xyz.com` request forward to `10.0.x.x`.

I want to host my all backend.

Answer (score 2):

[mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) is probably the most appropriate choice for this task.